# External editor for Stata on Linux

Tags: text-editor, stata

I just started using Stata 11 on Ubuntu, and realized its text-editor doesn't have any coloring features like Windows version. Could anybody advise me about some external editor that is easy to use and install? And with option to execute do/ado files directly from editor? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim can do this, though it has a steep learning curve: I've been using for about 15 years, mostly because I can't figure out how to exit it.

You will need the [syntax file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=440). Sending do-files/lines to Stata is pretty straightforward.

Comment: i will try it, does it work with mata files as well?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "work". Vim certainly does some syntax colouring for .mata and .do files. But note that the Vim approach as implemented by Jeff Pitblado's syntax file does not guarantee highlighting  precisely as you would want it done. Some implementations of Stata syntax highlighting emphasise highlighting command names, which in my experience isn't as helpful as you might think. But even partial highlighting helps greatly in spotting some silly errors (and adding a little colour, which isn't trivial to the computing experience).

Comment: Vim is great if you give it weeks to sink in, but distasteful to many either on first acquaintance or even when giving it a good try. (Witness Vim/Emacs discussions.)

Comment: thank you for the answer! Yeah, i was thinking on the same highlighting features since i have tried emacs where it works on a/do files but not in .mata ones ... btw, i am a bit confused with uninstalling Vim, i understood from the above answer that it is problematic..makes me bit scared to mess with it since i am just stata beginner

Comment: @nov mata is supported. The "can't exit" part was a bit of a joke that may not have gotten across. Installation and removal is a breeze. Often, it is already installed, or at least vi is.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good solution 
http://ess.r-project.org/

Comment: thanks for posting it, i tried it out, but except from highlighting it doesn't allow me to execute from there... at least i can't make it work in ubuntu

Comment: I am not an emacs expert but I think that with some tricks you can  add the functionalities that you need.  By the way I use stata 13 on ubuntu and the editor color the text

Answer (score 0):

**SynWrite** (run on Wine on Ubuntu) has Stata highlighter: install via Options/AddonsManager.

Not sure but maybe can run Stata too: call "Options/ External tools" dialog and configure command in it.